# Visual Studio Code - displaying of VB.NET code errors

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-code

If I open some old VB.NET code in VS Code, I actually do see the objects, types etc. in different color, so the code is recognized by editor.
However, what makes the code hard to read is that almost everything is highlighted as error (understandably because editor doesn't support VB.NET).

How can I switch-off error-checking so I can see the code without red underscores?
I don't mean to write code, compile it etc. I just want to be able to read and analyze it normally.

[image]

I didn't stress this enough: I don't need to debug, I don't need to write code, I don't need to compile it... I just want to read it normally without all those red snakes all over  :P

Comment: when you open a new project....you don't have the issue? look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098333/visual-studio-compiles-fine-but-still-shows-red-lines

Comment: Nope, it's just "out of space" page inserted in my angular project which I open to see and read the code. But readibility would be much better if there are no red snakes all over.

Comment: then disable intelli sense. also look at the link i posted. there is many reason why it would do that.

Comment: Disabling intellisense didn't work:     "[vb]": {
        "editor.quickSuggestions": false,
        "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false,
        "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false
    },
It's not that I want to fix the code, to find out what causes the red underlines, but I want to be able to read even syntatically wrong code, but I can't concentrate with all those red snakes around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS Code does support VB.NET.  What is your file extension?  Down in the bottom-right (status bar) you can see (& change) the currently selected language.

Note/edit: to fully answer your question, you could instead select Plain Text as the language, this will also get rid of all that highlighting.

Comment: this worked. after trying to disabling bunch of settings, I just switched this page (that was recognized as HTML) to VB and the "snakes" dissapeared,

Answer (score 0):

Making errors and warnings transparent:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorError.border": "#0000",
    "editorError.foreground": "#0000",
    "editorWarning.border": "#0000",
    "editorWarning.foreground": "#0000",
},
```

Comment: Making it invisible is not a real solution for the problem.

Comment: What is your solution then?

Comment: :D  I agree with Alex.  It's not a code problem / syntax error / whatever that I need to debug. I just want to READ the code WITHOUT all those red snakes all over

Comment: @Alex: thanks, I'll try it this evening and let you know

Comment: Doesn't work. I got error "Unknown configuration setting" and green underscore of the properties editorError.border, editorError.foreground...

Comment: What version of code are you using? The latest stable is **1.19.2**