# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Edition shows error lines in each line of code but the application runs successfully

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am working on Asp core project, when i open it in vs 2017 each line appears with red underlines, but runing the project works just fine, i tried to delete .vs folder, obj, bin then clean the project and rebuild it, but the problem still shown.

Any Help?

Comment: Are you referring to the Views? That's something that's been present in VS for years now. Usually it disappears after a few seconds.

Comment: no even in controllers, ant it does not disappear

Comment: Have your tried this: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21098333/visual-studio-compiles-fine-but-still-shows-red-lines"? Also try reloading your project.

Comment: yes i tried all of these, also to be mentioned i have the following error in the intellisense output : [Failure] Could not find file 'C:\Users\Msys\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs'.